# Add an arrow to a facetted ggplot, outside the plot, on just one facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

My plot currently looks like this[image: plot]

And I want there to be a single arrow to left of the Y axis pointing at the axis, as well as text by the arrow.

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
co2_diff_2050 %>%   
  ggplot( aes( Year, MTC, fill = Sector ) ) +
  geom_bar( position = "stack", stat = "identity" ) +
  scale_fill_manual( values = CO2_sector_color ) +
  scale_x_continuous( name = "Year", breaks = c( 2050 ) ) +
  scale_y_continuous( name = "MTC", breaks = c( 0, 5, 10 ), limits = c( -1, 13 ) ) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2049.5, y = maryland_80goal, xend = 2049.8, yend = maryland_80goal),
            arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm"))) +
  geom_errorbar( aes( ymin = net_diff, ymax = net_diff ), color = "gray30", linetype = "longdash", width = 1, size = 1 ) +
  geom_hline( yintercept = 0 ) +
  theme_bw() +
  guides( fill = guide_legend( ncol = 1 ) ) +
  theme( legend.position = "right" ) +
  labs( title = "Maryland Remaining CO2 Emissions by Sector in 2050",
        caption = "Arrow indicates Maryland's 2050 GHG emissions reduction goal
        Dashed gray line indicates emissions with biomass offset") +
  facet_wrap( ~ Scenario, nrow = 1 )
```

Comment: You mean that the arrow should be located outside/left of the plot and point towards the y axis?

Comment: @zoowalk Correct! I'll add a picture of what I'm aiming for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kind of a hacky solution but it seems to work. We make a `geom_segment()` without any mapped aesthetics, so that scales aren't trained on these. However, we do add the `data` argument, just to indicate which panel the arrow should appear next to. Now normally, this wouldn't appear because it is out of bounds, but we can set `clip = "off"` to show it anyway.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(
    # Change the 0 and 25's to be appropriate to your data
    x = 0, xend = -Inf, y = 25, yend=  25,
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(5, "pt")),
    # Add facetting variable appropriate to your data
    data = data.frame(cyl = 4)
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  facet_wrap(~ cyl, ncol = 4)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! One question. For `data = data.frame( cyl = 4 )` I tried various panel indicators such as `data = data.frame( Scenario == "highEV" ) `, `data = data.frame( Scenario = highEV ) `, and I get  **Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Sector' not found**. Am I interpreting this wrong? I want the arrow by the first panel, when Scenario is highEV.

Comment: The `data = data.frame(Scenario = "highEV")` sounds correct to me. The error I suspect might be due to inherited aesthetics, so probably you might want to add `inherit.aes = FALSE` to the segment. Alternatively you could also move the `fill = Sector` specification to `geom_bar(aes(fill = Sector), ...)` and then it shouldn't interfere downstream. None of this I have tested.